# Array is sorted, but React is not rendering in sorted order

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have the following code..

```
{
     this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
         qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
             qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) => 
                !defectsArray.includes(qc3.Defect) && defectsArray.sort() && defectsArray.push(qc3.Defect) &&
                  (<div className="row label">
                        <div className="column-label bold">{qc3.Defect}</div>
                    </div>)
           )
         )
      )
   }
```

When I use `console.log("DefectsArray",defectsArray)`

My array is printed and sorted in the console (my desired order)

```
0: "Bruise"
1: "Hail damage"
2: "Sunburn"
3: "Scuff"
```

However, react is actually rendering it "Sunburn, Bruise, Hail damage, Scuff" - basically unordered

**How do I achieve the output that is printed in my `console.log`?**

EDIT: Inside of the object..

```
`Array(20)
0:
BinsByDayByOrchardsAreas: null
BinsByDayByOrchardsCountries: null
BinsByDayByOrchardsPickers: null
BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: Array(1)
0:
BinsByDayByOrchards: null
BinsByDayByOrchardsID: null
BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects: Array(4)
0: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Sunburn", Count: 1, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
1: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Bruise", Count: 2, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
2: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Hail damage", Count: 0, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
3: {BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsID: "-LbiHz7tuuJH71I_4IKw", Defect: "Scuff", Count: 2, BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs: null}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting mapped properties from array JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821621/sorting-mapped-properties-from-array-javascript)

Comment: @Dom link is broken!

Comment: what is the structure of qc ?

Comment: @NihalSaxena I've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple working example for your reference as a code snippet!

```js
function App(){
  return(
    [ "Hail damage", "Sunburn","Bruise","Scuff"].sort().map((s)=><div>{s}</div>)
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However your code is so flawed, it does't make sense at all.
For starters you are sorting the defects array but you are showing(rendering) values that are in the qc3 array!

Move the function to generate strings for display into another function. I have fixed the rest of the implementation to be more readable!

```
getDisplayValues() {
    let displayedDefects = [];
    this.state.rows.map((qc) =>
        qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.map((qc2) =>
            qc2.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCsDefects.map((qc3) =>
                if(defectsArray.includes(qc3.Defect)){
                    displayedDefects.push(qc3.Defect);
                }
            )
        )
    );

    displayedDefects.sort();

    return displayedDefects.map((defect)=>( 
      <div className = "row label" >
          <div className = "column-label bold" > {defect} </div>
      </div> );

}

render(){
    return {this.getDisplayValues()}               
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, fixed some syntax but displayedDefects is empty, but yes you are right, I was sorting the defectsArray but displaying qc3.Defects....that was my attempt at sorting the array and displaying it